# VSCODE faill to install tools in go module

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, go-modules

when starting a go module on VSCode I get prompted to install some tool

[image]

choosing install the installation fails, below the logs in vscode terminal

VSCODE keeps yelling at me an "fail to install" stuff, simply because ignores my path
as you can see below

```
Tools environment: GOPATH=/home/go
Installing 1 tool at /home/go/bin in module mode.
  gopls

Installing golang.org/x/tools/gopls FAILED

1 tools failed to install.

gopls: failed to install gopls(golang.org/x/tools/gopls): Error: Command failed: /usr/local/go/bin/go get -v golang.org/x/tools/gopls
go: writing stat cache: mkdir /home/go: permission denied
go: downloading golang.org/x/tools/gopls v0.5.1
go: downloading golang.org/x/tools v0.0.0-20201017001424-6003fad69a88
go get golang.org/x/tools/gopls: mkdir /home/go: permission denied
 undefined
```

these are my `GOPATH` and `GOROOT`

```sh
# GOLANG
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$GOROOT/bin:$PATH
```

and this is my vscode `settings.json`

```json
{
    "[dart]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.formatOnType": true,
        "editor.rulers": [
            80
        ],
        "editor.selectionHighlight": false,
        "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
        "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
        "editor.tabCompletion": "onlySnippets",
        "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false
    },
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "One Dark Pro",
    "dart.sdkPath": "/home/francesco/development/dart",
    "dart.openDevTools": "flutter",
    "go.formatTool": "goimports",
    "dart.checkForSdkUpdates": false,
    "go.useLanguageServer": true,
    "go.inferGopath": false,
    "go.gopath": "/home/go",
    "go.goroot": "/usr/local/go"
}
```

what action should I take to fix the error?

Comment: What is the value of `$HOME`? It should point to your home folder, but from your logs it seems it points to `/home`. It should be e.g. `/home/francesco`.

Comment: yup! that's it, changing "go.path": "/home/francesco/go" in settings.json solves the issue! thank you <3
if care about getting reputation, make it as an answer I'll accept it straight away

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your error is:

```
go: writing stat cache: mkdir /home/go: permission denied
```

Go tries to write to `/home/go`. This folder is derived from:

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
```

So it looks your `$HOME` doesn't point to your home folder. `GOPATH` should point to a folder where you have write permission, because the module cache is located under `GOPATH`. So it should point to a folder under your user home, e.g. `/home/francesco/go`.

Answer (score 2):

I recently solved this problem on my Windows machine. At first I had thought it was a file permissions problem. But it was a GOPATH environment variable problem.

I had it set to 2 values: C:\Program Files\Go (which is where I installed Go) and C:.... which was where I wanted all my Go projects to go.

So I removed the first entry. Just leaving GOPATH to point to the place on my hard drive where I wanted all my projects, and hey presto, problems gone, all tools installed correctly.

This may have been due to a previous version of Go not being entirely removed.

Comment: Thanks, I also had to add GOPATH with C:\

Answer (score -1):

On fedora linux, go was installed to /usr/local/go/bin/go
The dir local/go and its subdirs and files were owned by root, and not my user.

Running codium as root wasn't an option because of course not, so running `sudo chown my_user_name /usr/local/go -R` was necessary, after which vscode was able to install missing go modules with the built in buttons for doing so.

Comment: It is not a good approach to change the ownership of system directories unnecessarily. The better approach would be to unset the `GOBIN` env variable, so that next time, VSCode saves the packages to your `GOPATH`/bin, which is always editable.